# Jquery Datatables : How to access attributes of td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Please excuse me, my English is not very good.

I have a datatable array with each row of this form :

```
<tr id="1234">
    <td id="td_mob_1234" colspan="2"> xxxxx </td>
    <td id="td_desk_1234" style="display: none;"> yyyy </td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
</tr>
```

At some point, I need to edit all the rows in the table.

- So I get the lines of the table.
- I'm making my changes.
- And I apply them that way.

  ```
  var data = datatable.rows().data();

  for (var i = 0, row; row = data[i]; i++) {

    // I'm making my changes. on row[0], row[1].....

    // apply
    datatable.row(i).data(row).draw();

  }
  ```

My problem is that row [0], row [1]…. contain only the inside of my `td`.

I would also need to access the attributes of my `td`, to change from `colspan = 2` to `colspan = 1` and from `display: none` to `display: block` for the second `td`.

How can I access and modify these attributes?

Thank you

Comment: so, are the changes css specific? if so, then just add a css class for your table that should be changed and declare the styles there.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with cell().node() :

```
var cell = datatable.cell("#id").node();
$(cell).attr('colspan', 1);
                    
var cell = datatable.cell("#id").node();
$( cell ).css( 'display', 'block' );
```

Thanks